# Does Hyperledger Fabric runtime create a new instance of Contract class every time when i call a method?

Tags: java, hyperledger-chaincode

I have a `CarTransfer Contract` Class. It has one method `createCar` and one instance variable `check`. The value of the `check` is initially 0. So every time when the `createCar` method is called, the `check` should be increased by 1. Theoretically, after the 5 method calls of `createCar`, the value of the `check` should be 5. But the problem is, the value of the variable `check` stays always 1. It only increases once but after that no increase.

When I make the variable static it works. but making a variable static is not a good practice. I want to know what is the root cause behind this problem.

Comment: Do you have one or multiple single CarTransfer Contract instances? If you could make sure there is only one instance, "check" variable should be increased as expected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.